# Custom mapping of categorical to numeric values

Tags: python, mapping

I have object type columns that have categorical values example 15-16 Years, 17-23 Years .....  I have converted them to category and then cat.codes. However,the coding values start from 0 for the first group 0-4 years and I want the coding to start from 1 ie 0-4->1, 5-12-> and @@->NaN
The suggested solution of using dictionary mapping still has issues. Following is mcve

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['0-4 Years', '5-12 Years','13-18 Years', '19-21 Years','22-25 Years','26-29 Years','30-35 Years',
        '36-41 Years','42-45 Years','46-49 Years','50-55 Years', '56-63 Years']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Age'],dtype=object)
df['Age']=df['Age'].astype('category')
cats = dict(enumerate(df['Age'].cat.categories, 2))
df['Age']=df['Age'].cat.codes.map(cats).astype('category')
df['Age']
```

and here is the output, as you can see if I change the enumeration start other than 0, there is an issue with values as NaN. Secondly the column is not coded either:

```
df['Age']
0             NaN
1     36-41 Years
2             NaN
3             NaN
4       0-4 Years
5     13-18 Years
6     19-21 Years
7     22-25 Years
8     26-29 Years
9     30-35 Years
10    42-45 Years
11    46-49 Years
Name: Age, dtype: category
Categories (9, object): [0-4 Years, 13-18 Years, 19-21 Years, 22-25 Years, ..., 30-35 Years, 36-41 Years, 42-45 Years, 46-49 Years]
```

How to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own dictionary that maps codes and categories with:

```
cats = dict(enumerate(df['Age'].cat.categories, 1))
```

And use this dictionary to map it in the dataframe

```
df['Age'].cat.codes.map(cats).astype('category')
```

Comment: But what do you want to store in the column, the codes themselves?

Comment: Also as I change the start of enumerate to any value higher than '1' then 
df['Age'] starts to have NaN for the categories where the mapping was available. The code upto cats is fine as I can see the categories based on dictionary but the second line seems to have an issue

Comment: The first line of code only creates a dictionary, so is not very useful on its own. That's why there a second line where you use the dictionary to map it to your dataframe.

Comment: Maybe if you had provided a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this would not be the issue. So I encourage you to edit your question with some more content that other people can use to provide a better answer.