# how to change the category code in a category column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv that I am reading using pandas.

In the csv, I have a column that has the following values:

```
x<1
1<x<2
2<x<3
3<x<4
x<4
```

when I convert them to category and then use category code, I am getting something such as this for category codes

```
{
x<1:2
1<x<2:1
2<x<3:3
3<x<4:4
x<4:0 
}
```

but I need the code to be as follow:

```
{
x<1:0
1<x<2:1
2<x<3:2
3<x<4:3
x<4:4 
}
```

How can I change the category code without changing the dataframe?

I used the following code to convert the column to category:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('category')
```

Comment: How are you converting the values into categories? I mean, the mapping where does it come from?

Comment: Anyways, if you're expecting a dict, you could simply create a new dict (which you could apply/map later). Does that help?

Comment: @aaossa Please see my updated question.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53423821/3281097) help?

Comment: df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df['col'], categories=df['col'])

Comment: @doesitmatter How this code changes the category code? Where the code is defined?

Comment: from your example 0..N-1 in the order of appearance is what I see. if thats only an example, you lack a representative mre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype` to change the category code follows:

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['x<1', '1<x<2', '2<x<3', '3<x<4', 'x<4']})
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('category')

# Get the current category order
category_order1 = df.col.cat.categories.to_list()
print('category_order_1:', category_order1)

# Invert the category order
co = category_order1[::-1]
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=co, ordered=True))

# Get the current category order
category_order2 = df.col.cat.categories.to_list()
print('category_order_2:', category_order2)

# Define and apply arbitrary category order
co = ['2<x<3', 'x<4', 'x<1', '3<x<4', '1<x<2']
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=co, ordered=True))

# Get the current category order
category_order3 = df.col.cat.categories.to_list()
print('category_order_3:', category_order3)
```

### Output:

```
category_order_1: ['1<x<2', '2<x<3', '3<x<4', 'x<1', 'x<4']
category_order_2: ['x<4', 'x<1', '3<x<4', '2<x<3', '1<x<2']
category_order_3: ['2<x<3', 'x<4', 'x<1', '3<x<4', '1<x<2']
```

Comment: the order in this code is the same as the way that defined in df, I am reading df from a csv, so I can not change the order that appears in the data frame.